# why does it show an error of 'ORA-04091' when I updated the data in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I use the code to create a table and a trigger in oracle apex. The code is as follows:
CREATE TABLE  "NEWSSUBSCRIBE"
(    "SUBNAME" VARCHAR2(20),
"SUBPHONE" NUMBER(*,0),
"SUBSCRIBEID" VARCHAR2(20),
"NEWSPAPERNAME" VARCHAR2(50),
"NEWSFREQUENCY" VARCHAR2(50),
"STARTDATE" DATE,
"ENDDATE" DATE,
"STOPSTARTDATE" DATE,
"STOPENDDATE" DATE,
"CANCELSUBSCRIBE" VARCHAR2(10),
"BALANCE" FLOAT(126),
"DUEAMOUNT" FLOAT(126),
PRIMARY KEY ("SUBSCRIBEID")
USING INDEX  ENABLE
)

insert
into newssubscribe
values(NULL,NULL,'XXXXXX',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "Stopsubscribe"
before update on newssubscribe
for each row
declare
daysnum integer;
begin
daysnum := to_date(:new.StopEndDate,'mm/dd/yyyy')-to_date(:new.StopStartDate,'mm/dd/yyyy');
update newssubscribe
set Balance = Balance + daysnum;
end;

When I update the row of data in the oracle apex application, it showed the error that 'ORA-04091: table WKSP_APEXHENRY.NEWSSUBSCRIBE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it'. The error is shown in the images as below:
[update the data-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Aep.png)
[update the data-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUh2d.png)
Because the row of data has several 'NULL', I want to update the row of data. How can I solve this problem?

I hope I can update the row of data successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can't at row level update the table you are triggering on.  Plenty of questions/answers here on SO if you search for "mutating".

Based on this trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "Stopsubscribe" 
before update on newssubscribe 
for each row declare
daysnum integer; 
begin 
  daysnum := to_date(:new.StopEndDate,'mm/dd/yyyy')-to_date(:new.StopStartDate,'mm/dd/yyyy'); 
  update newssubscribe set Balance = Balance + daysnum;
 end;
```

You should be able to achieve this all with this just :new assigments, ie

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "Stopsubscribe" 
    before update on newssubscribe 
    for each row declare
    daysnum integer; 
    begin 
      daysnum := to_date(:new.StopEndDate,'mm/dd/yyyy')-to_date(:new.StopStartDate,'mm/dd/yyyy'); 
      :new.Balance = :new.Balance + daysnum;
     end;
```